# How to prove this 3-part function is bijective?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove a function $f$ is bijective. To prove this, I'll first throw in a theorem that we can use:

Let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q>0$. Then

1. if $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $q\neq 1$, then there exists unique prime numbers $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_N$ and unique exponents $r_1,\cdots,r_N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
   \begin{align}
               q=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_N^{r_N}\;\;(1)
           \end{align}
2. if $q\notin \mathbb{N}$, then there exists unique prime numbers $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_N$, $q_1<q_2<\cdots<q_M$ with $p_i\neq q_j$ for all $i\in\{1,\cdots,N\},j\in\{1,\cdots,M\}$, and unique exponents $r_1,\cdots,r_N,s_1,\cdots,s_M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
   \begin{align}
               q=\frac{p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_N^{r_N}}{q_1^{s_1}q_2^{s_2}\cdots q_M^{s_M}}\;\;(2)
           \end{align}

Now we define this function $f:\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q>0\}\to\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

- $f(1)=1$
- if $q\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$ is given by (1), then
  \begin{align*}
          f(q)=p_1^{2r_1}p_2^{2r_2}\cdots p_N^{2r_N}
      \end{align*}
- if $q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is given by (2), then
  \begin{align*}
          f(q)=p_1^{2r_1}p_2^{2r_2}\cdots p_N^{2r_N}q_1^{2s_1-1}q_2^{2s_2-1}\cdots q_M^{2s_M-1}
      \end{align*}
  For example,
  \begin{align*}
      f\left(\frac{4}{15}\right)&=2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5\\
      f(q)&=108=2^2\cdot 3^3\implies p_1=2,r_1=1,q_1=3,s_1=2\implies q=\frac{2^1}{3^2}=\frac{2}{9}
  \end{align*}

Now I want to prove $f$ is bijective: $f$ is 1-1 and onto. Here is my proof so far:

1. 1-1: I want to show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. Suppose there exists $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=1$, then $x_1=x_2=1$

If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\rightarrow p_1^{2r_1}\cdots p_N^{2r_N}={p'_1}^{2r_1'}\cdots {p_N'}^{2r_N'} \implies p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_N^{r_N}={p_1'}^{r_1'}\cdots {p_N'}^{r_N'}$ since $p,q,r,s$ are natural numbers. Thus, $x_1=x_2$

- **I don't know how to prove the third part is also 1-1**

1. Onto: I want to show that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(q)=n$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

- When $n=1$, we have $f(1)=1\implies q=1$. Therefore, $q$ exists.
- When $n$ is a perfect square, set the $n$ to be $n^2$. we have $f(q)=p_1^{2r_1}p_2^{2r_2}\cdots p_N^{2r_N}=n^2\implies q=n$. Therefore, $q$ exists.
- **Again, I don't know how to show the 3rd part is also onto.**

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm learning real analysis by myself and I really don't have anyone to ask.

Comment: I don't think values like $q = \frac13$ (numerator $1$) are covered in equation (2), are they?

Comment: @MPW I would say the exponent in the numerator is 0. I think in some cases, natural numbers contain 0?

Comment: No, because then you lose uniqueness since you can always throw in $p^0$. I'm just pointing out that you have to be really careful about the basic definitions here.

Comment: @MPW I didn't think of this. Thank you for pointing that out. This theorem is taken from here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/resources/mit18_100af20_hw1/